# Receiving D2C messages from an IoT Hub in browser

Tags: azure, dashboard, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

I am working on a simple dashboard for showing IoT data in a browser.
So far, I was using the Paho MQTT client library and a public MQTT broker to receive data. However, I'd like to use the Azure IoT Hub from now on.

The data I'm sending is just simple temperature and humidity values.

I already found out that I can't connect to the IoT Hub via MQTT. 
So my question is:
Is there a possibility to connect (eg. using javascript) directly to IoT Hub and read the data?
If not, what's my best option?

I thought about saving the messages to an SQL Database and reading from that, but that seems quite complicated for what should be a simple IoT use case (showing real-time data)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to IoT Hub via MQTT.  Please take a look at this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support) for detail.  We also have a [Node.js SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node) for connecting to IoT Hub if you don't want to deal with MQTT directly.  I know you are working on your own dashboard, but have you looked at [Azure IoT Solutions Accelerator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/iot-accelerators/)?  It's completely open source and you can modify it as you want.